# Sequence contains more than one matching element when adding a migration

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, tph

The following code in my DbContext class causes an error when I try to add a migration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskExt>()
            .Map<TaskDespatch>(m => { m.Requires("WorkStationID").HasValue(160).HasColumnType("int"); });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do I need to map all possible values for the WorkStationID discriminator column?

Answer (score 1):

The field name was "WorkstationID" in the database.  Correcting the "S" to be lower case stopped the message.